# Taylor& Francis Manuscript status from "Awaiting Editorial Office Processing" to "Under Review" in 3 days

Tags: publications, peer-review, journal-workflow, paper-submission

I submitted a manuscript in a journal (Taylor&Francis) and after 3 days the status of my MS changed from "Awaiting Editorial Office Processing" to "Under Review". What does this mean?

Comment: What else could it mean besides it's now under review?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)